# How can I insert page number to rmarkdown beamer slides?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

How can I show page numbers (preferably like 4/10, 5/10 etc.) on an rmarkdown beamer presentation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the front matter of the document, you can include a .tex file with extra commands as shown in RStudio's documentation [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html#includes).

I created a new .tex file that I called "header_pagenrs.tex" which only includes the top 2 lines from @user4281727's answer:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
```

Then I referenced this file at the top of my .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Things and Stuff"
author: "Me"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: header_pagenrs.tex
---
```

If this still gives you errors, you might also be missing some required TeX packages (a separate problem from RStudio and rmarkdown).

Comment: Is it possible to remove the page number from the title page?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how!

Comment: @civilstat I have been using this script for well over a year now, but today it is failing... MAC OSX 10.13.6, R 3.5.2 RStudio 1.1.463. To clarify: same exact document, just recompiling. Now no page number outputs... the `header_pagenrs.tex` file seems to be causing the `include: ... theme:` output to malfunction as well

Comment: After updating all LaTeX packages, this is largely resolved. The theme I was using ("Malmoe") still has problems; but a switch to a new theme resolves.

Comment: Glad to hear that updating packages helped. Unfortunately I have no ideas about how to fix the issue with your original theme.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option that worked for me. Didn't need to add a .tex file to my folder. Just included the following (based on above code from @civilstat) at the top of my Markdown doc.

```
---
title: 'Your Title'
author: "Your Name"
date: "July 4, 1776"
output:
  beamer_presentation(keep_tex = TRUE): default

header-includes:

- \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
- \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
---
```

Answer (score 2):

If your beamer version is reasonable up to date (>= v3.48), you can adjust the format of the frame numbers while keeping the footline of your chosen beamer theme unchanged otherwise.

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Berlin"
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
---

test
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't do a thing with pandoc.  What am I missing?

Comment: @dearN Is your beamer version new enough? (>=v3.48)

Comment: How do I check (beamer version) via command line?  You ask a pertinent question.

Comment: @dearN There should be a .log file in the same folder as the .tex file.This log file should include the version number

Comment: There is no log file... I am using `pandoc -t beamer foo.md -o foo.pdf`.

Comment: @dearN I don't know if this rmarkdown syntax with the header includes works for markdown. if yes the `keep_tex` option should make sure that the log file is also kept

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the lines below into the template

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

~/Library/R/3.1/library/rmarkdown/rmd/beamer/default.tex
```