# Frame number in Quarto beamer presentation

Tags: r, latex, beamer, quarto

I am preparing a Quarto presentation using beamer and would like to add the frame number at the bottom of each slide (analogous to the slide-number option in revealjs).
Could anybody tell me how I can do this?

I already figured out that the slide-number option does not exist for beamer.

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file so we can see which theme you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you can control it yourself like this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048437/how-can-i-insert-page-number-to-rmarkdown-beamer-slides))

```
---
title: "Presentation"
format: 
  beamer: 
    aspectratio: 32
    navigation: horizontal
    header-includes: |
       \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
       \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
---

# Intro


## second slide
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for since it is independent of the template - thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The default theme does not include slide numbering, but you could use one with, e.g. `Boadilla`:

```r
---
title: "Slide numbering in Beamer"
format: 
  beamer:
    theme: Boadilla
editor: visual
---
```

[image]